# How to handle pct_change with negative values

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating percentage change for a panel dataset, which has both positive and negative values. If both values of n and n+1 date are negative and values of n > n+1, for instance, n=-2, n+1=-4. The calculated percentage change is ((n+1)-n)/n=((-4)-(-2))/-2=1. As you can see the change should be a downtrend, which is expected to be negative but the result is the opposite. I normally set the denominators the absolute values ((n+1)-n)/abs(n) in other software to ensure the direction of the trend. Just wondering if I can do so in Python pandas pct_change to set up the denominator to be absolute values. Many thanks. I have solved the question based on the answer from Leo.

Here is a data example if one wants to play around.

```
import pandas as pd
df= {'id':[1,1,2,2,3,3],'values':[-2,-4,-2,2,1,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=df)
df['pecdiff']=(df.groupby('id')['values'].apply(lambda x:x.diff()/x.abs().shift()
)).fillna(method=bfill)
```

Comment: Could you add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and expected output? Without any context it seems you're lookin for [`pandas.DataFrame.abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html).

Comment: The description is very clear and Leo understood it very well and has solved the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the line for `expected change` should solve your problem. For comparison, I put side by side pandas' method and what you need.

The following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([-2,-4,-2,2,1], columns = ['Values'])
df['pct_change'] = df['Values'].pct_change()

# This should help you out:
df['expected_change'] = df['Values'].diff() / df['Values'].abs().shift()
df
```

Gives this output. Note that the signs are different for lines 1 through 3

```
    Values  pct_change  expected_change
0       -2        NaN               NaN
1       -4        1.0              -1.0
2       -2       -0.5               0.5
3        2       -2.0               2.0
4        1       -0.5              -0.5
```

Comment: Hi, any idea how it goes with groupby()? since it's a panel dataset.

Comment: dfy1=df.groupby('id')['y1'].diff()/df['y1'].abs().shift().fillna(method='bfill').to_frame()

Comment: Did that solve your second question? I didn't understand what you need and what you mean by a 'panel dataset'.

If you are still having trouble, please edit your post like @MrNobody33 suggested, so that we can view the problem the same way as you do.

Comment: Hi panel data is a dataset with two indices, e.g. date, id. My dataset is too complicated and posting an example here would cost me more time to organise it. That didn't solve my second question. I am trying to solve it myself.

Comment: @SHendricks did you figure out how to do the above connected to a groupby function?